c++ and IStream.Read()
I am trying to capture the screen,then transfer it to byte stream, in order to send it to the network.
But the stream->Read() doesn't work.The once_read always 0, and there is not data in buf.
I don't konw if there are better ways to do this.
HDC hdc = NULL;
if (hWnd == NULL) { hWnd = GetDesktopWindow(); }
hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
if (hdc == NULL) { return false; }
int bitOfpix = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, BITSPIXEL);
int width = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);
int height = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES);

CImage image;
IStream* stream;

CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, true, &stream);

image.Create(width, height, bitOfpix);
// PrintWindow(hWnd, image.GetDC(), PW_CLIENTONLY | PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT);
BitBlt(image.GetDC(), 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

image.Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
image.Save(name.data());

STATSTG stat;
stream->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME);
ULONGLONG size = stat.cbSize.QuadPart;
char* buf = new char[4096];
memset(buf, 0, 4096);
int once_read = 0;

while (size > 0)
{
  HRESULT res = stream->Read(buf, min(size, 4095), (ULONG *)&once_read);
  std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  size -= once_read;
}

image.ReleaseDC();
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

I want to know how to transfer a CImage to a byte array, then use send() to send it to the network.

CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, true, &stream) creates an empty stream. It is not a surprise that reading from it returns zero bytes.

The cast in (ULONG *)&once_read looks very fishy. Use the appropriate type for once_read.

I have show more code.

Start adding error checks, for example you don't check if CreateStreamOnHGlobal succeeds.

I have try it just now, it return S_OK. I think it mean success.

@loverinmydream please make that clear in the question, either in the code or explicitely in the question text. And yes S_OK obviously means success, at least that's what the documentation says.

if I do this char buf[4096] = { 0 };   char buf1[4096] = { 0 };   scanf_s("%s", buf1, 4096);   stream->Write(buf, 4096, NULL);   stream->Read(buf1, 4096, NULL);
I can get what I input;
So I thing the problem is on image.Save(stream).
The windows document doesn't say how to use it.

You probably must call stream->Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr) before trying to read from it

@SimonMourier that's useful.

@IInspectable CreateStreamOnHGlobal() indeed creates an empty stream, but the stream is not empty anymore by the time the OP tries to read from it. They are just reading from the wrong position inside the stream.

@RemyLebeau I was commenting on revision 1.

After you save the image to the stream, the stream's seek pointer is positioned at the end of the stream. Read() reads from the current seek pointer, so there is no data to read at the end of the stream.
You need to rewind the seek pointer back to the beginning of the stream before you can read what was saved in the stream, eg:
image.Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);

...

// ADD THIS!
LARGE_INTEGER pos;
pos.QuadPart = 0;
stream->Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);

...

ULONG once_read = 0;
stream->Read(buf, min(size, 4095), &once_read);


Not sure this is the issue as ISequentialStream::Read() typically returns S_FALSE (as opposed to S_OK) when it reaches the end of the stream. Regardless, stream->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr) is (or should be) the more conventional spelling for "rewinding a stream in C++".

@IInspectable why would this not be the issue? Of course it is. The OP is trying to read from the end of the stream, hence why there is no data being returned.

The asker claims that they are receiving S_OK while ISequentialStream::Read() would return S_FALSE when returning fewer bytes than requested due to reading past the end.

@IInspectable the OP didn't actually say what "it" referred to in their comment, but in the context of that discussion I think they may have been referring to CreateStreamOnHGlobal() returning S_OK, not Read() returning S_OK. But whatever, its moot at this point.

Both CreateStreamOnHGlobal() and Read() return S_OK, I don't know why, but that's really true.
